# MySQL Foreign Key value is NULL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am trying to create a table called "Borrower" or "Lånetagare" and want to insert the value from table Lån with the ID from there. The result I get is NULL. How come?

```
    create table Lån
(
Lån_ID INT auto_increment primary key,
Lånedatum DATETIME,
Inlämningsdatum DATETIME,
Omlån DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO Lån (Lånedatum, Inlämningsdatum, Omlån)

VALUES ('2017-09-12', '2017-09-15', '2017-09-15');

CREATE TABLE Lånetagare
( 
Lånetagare_ID INT(10) auto_increment primary key,
Lösenord varchar(50),
Förnamn varchar(50),
Efternamn varchar(50),
Adress varchar (50),
Ort varchar(50),
Postnummer int(5),
Email varchar(50),
Telefonnummer int(20),
Lånekort int(50),
Lån_ID int(50),
FOREIGN KEY (Lån_ID) REFERENCES Lån(Lån_ID)
);

INSERT INTO Lånetagare (Lösenord, Förnamn, Efternamn, Adress, Ort, Postnummer, Email, Telefonnummer, Lånekort)
VALUES ('hej135', 'Victor', 'Chi', 'Blekingegatan 28', 'Stockholm', 11856, 'Tim@hotmail.com', 0704582235, 56);

SELECT * FROM Lånetagare;
```

Comment: you never insert Lan_ID in your second insert statement, therefore the FK is null since it is never assigned a value

Comment: what you can do is append this into your second insert statement so it includes `insert into  Lånetagare (Lån_ID) Values (LAST_INSERT_ID())` in mysql that will insert the last auto_increment read more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24423795/3404097

Answer (score 1):

If you want to associate a row in `Lånetagare` with the previously-inserted row in `Lån`, you must set a value for the foreign key.

Here's a common way to do it:

```
INSERT INTO Lån (Lånedatum, Inlämningsdatum, Omlån)
VALUES ('2017-09-12', '2017-09-15', '2017-09-15');

INSERT INTO Lånetagare (...other columns..., Lån_ID)
VALUES (...other values..., LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

The LAST_INSERT_ID() function returns the most recent auto-increment id created by an INSERT statement during your session. Read more about this function here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
INSERT INTO Lånetagare (Lösenord, Förnamn, Efternamn, Adress, Ort, Postnummer, Email, Telefonnummer, Lånekort, Lån_ID)
VALUES ('hej135', 'Victor', 'Chi', 'Blekingegatan 28', 'Stockholm', 11856, 'Tim@hotmail.com', 0704582235, 56, (SELECT Lån_ID FROM Lån WHERE <put your select criteria here>));
```

Comment: `Lån_ID` is `INT`, why are you setting it to `'2017-09-12'`?