# Relation table does not update when I insert records

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

Maybe this could be a stupid question. Ok, so I created the following table:

```
create table USER(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    firstname varchar(50) not null,
    lastname varchar(50) not null,
    password varchar(20) not null,
    emailU varchar(100) not null
);

create table POST(
    ID_User int,
    ID_Tweet int,
    primary key(ID_User, ID_Tweet),
    foreign key(ID_User) references USER(ID) on update cascade on delete cascade,
    foreign key(ID_Tweet) references TWEET(ID) on update cascade on delete cascade
);

create table TWEET(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    Text varchar(200)
);
```

When I insert something, for example:

```
insert into USER (firstname, lastname, password, emailU) values ('X', 'Y', 'XY', 'xy@gmail.com');
```

and

```
insert into TWEET (text) values ('Something');
```

It updates correctly the tables USER and TWEET, but the table POST remains empty. Why? It should be updated with the ID_User and ID_Tweet or I get wrong?

Comment: You have to INSERT into posts as well...

Comment: The post table doesn't get automatically populated, you have to populate it.  How should the DB know that the TWEET(s) you just inserted are for which USER(s)?

Comment: Please don't save passwords as plain text in your database. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database

Comment: Ok, but I'm not supposed to know the IDs of tweets and users cause they are int AutoIncrement, so how can I insert those informations in the table POST?

@Juan Carlos Oropeza, yes this is just a first draft of the project ;)

Comment: Different databases let you access that id created by IDENTITY or AUTOINCREMENT fields.  SQL Server has `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, MySQL has `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, SQLite has `sqlite3_set_last_insert_rowid()`, etc, etc, etc.  So, when you create a user, you can find out what `id` it was given, when you insert a tweet you can find out what `id` it was given, then you can populated `post`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup relationship between tables In phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421055/how-to-setup-relationship-between-tables-in-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

`foreing key` is just a constraint, to keep your table consistency, so you dont have the wrong data there (like orphan post without any user). So as MatBailie say the data doesn't get populated automatically.

You didnt specify your rdbms but after insert you need to get the last_insert id. for example in Sql Server

[How to get last inserted id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

And then you use it to create a new record on the table `post`.

Also maybe your model is too simple but right now I dont see the need for you to have the table `POST` because not new data is add it to the relation.

So is better if you include the `user_id` field to the tweet

```
create table TWEET(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    Text varchar(200),
    ID_User int,
    foreign key(ID_User) references USER(ID) on update cascade on delete cascade,
);
```